Karhunen–Loève theorem expansion random variables
In the Karhunen–Loève theorem's statement the random variables in the expansion are given by $$Z_k = \int_a^b X_te_k(t) \: dt$$
$X_t$ is a zero-mean square-integrable stochastic process defined over a probability space $(\Omega, F, P)$ and indexed over a closed and bounded interval $[a, b]$, with continuous covariance function $K_X(s, t)$.
$e_k(t)$ are elements of an orthonormal basis on $L^2([a, b])$ formed by the eigenfunctions of the linear operator $T_{K_{X}}$ with respective eigenvalues $\lambda_k$. As explained here $L^2([a, b])$ is the Hilbert space of measurable square functions defined on the space $([a,b], \mathcal B([a,b], P)$ that have finite measure. Note that $\mathcal B([a,b])$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on the closed set $[a,b]$ and $P$ is the Lebesgue measure on it.
I'm confused about the meaning of the integral involved in the definition of random variables $Z_k$.
Which kind of integral is this ?

It seems that integral requires a measurable stochastic process -- i.e. its sample paths must be Lebesgue integrable over the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $[a,b]$. Did I get it right ?
